# Soundcloud api get user tracks

Tags: soundcloud

I am using soundcloud resolve. This example is working:

```
http://api.soundcloud.com/resolve.json?url=https://soundcloud.com/katermukke/tracks&client_id=CLIENT_ID
```

However this is not working:

```
http://api.soundcloud.com/resolve.json?url=https://soundcloud.com/ferry-corsten/tracks&client_id=CLIENT_ID
```

If you add CLIENT_ID and open in browser you will see the results. Second one returns empty array.

Can anybody explain why?

Comment: Can you detail what  you mean by "is not working"? What happens and what do you  expect to happen? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Put api key and try in browser. It returns empty array.

Comment: Some tracks are private and won't show up in the API, only the SoundCloud website.

Comment: Is there a way to detect private tracks if they cant be retrieved?

Comment: Same sort of issue with https://soundcloud.com/johnocallaghan/tracks. Granted, some tracks are private, but others are not (e.g. podcast episodes). Through the API: "https://api.soundcloud.com/users/324536/tracks?client_id=CLIENT_ID", an empty array is returned, whereas for other artists it is not empty.